# Plotting multi variable time data

Tags: gnuplot

I have some reasonably simple data that I am wanting to plot, ideally as a histogram or line graph but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Here is some sample data:

```
T Item Temp
1 Leaf 10
1 Car  12
2 Leaf 14
3 Car  23
4 Car  29 
4 Leaf 30
```

In this example T is the time, Item is the item name and Temp is the items temperature at this time.

I've got a few issues with trying to graph this:

- Item is tracked as rows instead of as a column
- There are implicit zeros.

If my data was in the following form it would be easier for me to plot, but unfortunately it's not formatted this way:

```
T Car Leaf 
1 12  10
2 0   14
3 24  0
4 29  30
```

Is gnuplot capable of plotting the former example, or do I have to write a preprocessor to reformat the provided data into the simpler to understand second one?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be done entirely in gnuplot. This should help you:

```
names=("Car Leaf")
plot for [name in names] 'test.txt' u 1:((stringcolumn(2)eq name?$3:0)) smooth freq with lp title name
```

type `help smooth` and `help stringcolumn` for more informations

if you want to **automatically** fill the `names` variable you can use this `system` command:

```
names=system("awk '{print $2}' test.txt | tail -n +2 | sort | uniq")
```

for `boxes` here is a suggestion:

```
set boxwidth 0.5/(words(names))
plot for [i=0:words(names)] 'test.txt' u ($1-0.5-i/(words(names)+1.0)):((stringcolumn(2)eq word(names,i)?$3:0)) smooth freq with boxes title word(names,i)
```

This is what you should get:

[image]